# Read outlook emails in databricks

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks

I would like to read mails from microsoft outlook using python and run the script using a databricks cluster.

I'm using win32com on my local machine and able to read emails. However, when i try to install the same package on databricks , it seems to throw an error saying

> DRIVER_LIBRARY_INSTALLATION_FAILURE. Error Message: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Process List(/databricks/python/bin/pip, install, pywin32, --disable-pip-version-check) exited with code 1. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32

sample code is as follows

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders

emails_list = [
'xyz@outlook.com'
]
subjects = []
categories = []
body_content = []
names = []
for id, name in enumerate(emails_list):
   
    folder = outlook(name)
    #print('Accessing email - ' , folder)
    inbox = folder.Folders("Inbox")
    message = inbox.Items
    message = message.GetFirst()
    body_content.append(message.Body)
    subjects.append(message.Subject)
    categories.append(message.Categories)
    names.append(name)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(names,subjects,categories,body_content)), 
             columns=['names','subjects','categories','body_content'])
df.head(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databricks clusters are using Linux (specifically, Ubuntu Linux), so you can't use COM library that is designed for Windows. Potentially you can access your emails in the Office 365 using IMAP protocol, or something like that (see [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353)).  Python has built-in `imaplib` library that could be used for that purpose, for example, like in the [following article](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/reading-emails-in-python).